# Running a vba macro as a string

Tags: string, vba, excel, ibm-doors

I am trying to run a macro which is not defined anywhere but in a string.

For example I have the following string:

```
Public Sub testMacro()
Dim MC As Range
Set MC = ActiveSheet.Range("A15")
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    MC.Offset(i, 0) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

I want to execute the code stored in this string from another program (Doors DXl). I know that you can execute a sub using Application.Run, but this only works using the name of the macro if the macro is already written in an Excel file.
I repeat that this sub **does not and will not** exist anywhere but in the previous string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
Eval
```

> You can use the Eval function to evaluate an expression that results
>   in a text string or a numeric value.
>
> You can construct a string and then pass it to the Eval function as if
>   the string were an actual expression. The Eval function evaluates the
>   string expression and returns its value. For example, Eval("1 + 1")
>   returns 2.
>
> If you pass to the Eval function a string that contains the name of a
>   function, the Eval function returns the return value of the function.
>   For example, Eval("Chr$(65)") returns "A".
>
> **Eval(stringexpr)**

from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172212%28v=office.11%29.aspx